# What does “to the left” mean?

Tags: equilibrium, water, terminology

> However, the concentration of hydronium and hydroxide ions will be very, very small; in fact, the equilibrium that's established in solution lies so far to the left, that only 18 in 10<sup>10</sup> molecules of water will undergo autoionization.

What does "to the left" mean in the extract above? Does it mean the left side of the chemical equation?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, "to the left" refers to the left side of an equilibrium expression.

Traditionally, the autoionization of water is written as

$$\ce{2H2O <=> H3O+ + OH-}$$

When we talk about equilibrium lying "to the left", it means that the educt/reactant is favored, i.e. more $\ce{H2O}$ than $\ce{H3O+}$ or $\ce{OH-}$.

Conversely, an equilibrium that lies "to the right" is one that favors products. In this case, it would favor the production of $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ over $\ce{H2O}$,